# Flex 4.5 RemoteObject and AMFPHP over SSL with self-signed certificate

Tags: apache-flex, ssl, amfphp, self-signed

I'm trying to connect to AMFPHP over SSL (self-signed) from a Flex 4.5 application.
Will this work? Or do I need an authority-signed certificate?
Will it silently fail or prompt user like it does in browser?
How do I need to edit the services-config.xml file for this to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before, and it works fine The one thing I'd suggest is that you make your page that houses the SWF on the same domain/cert, then the browser will prompt the user to accept the certificate before they even see the SWF. Once the cert is manually accepted, the AMFPHP stuff works fine. The default services-config should work fine but you can edit it to accept ONLY ssl connections for more security. The only IE issue I can remember off the top of my head is that there's a checkbox if your server sends the wrong caching header (no-cache) I think, IE will simply show a redx. This is resolved by changing a checkbox in IE.

I've never tried doing the client page on HTTP and the services on HTTPS but I imagine you might run into more issues that way.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for that. However, what I want is to use a RemoteObject over a self-signed SSL certificate. No browser. And definitely not the same domain.